# Web service with Axis2 without using eclipse plugin

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

Just wanted to know can we create web service with Axis2 **without using eclipse plugin**.

If yes please share how can i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible,
Quick start with example here : http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/quickstartguide.html